# Symmetry dictates the answer

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry

I'm quite new to Electrodynamics and while I was reading about that topic (at http://textbook.scotthill.us/05-FieldLines/03-Symmetry.php) I came across the following statement:

> An electric field has the same symmetries as the source charges that created it.

I can see it holds for rotation and reflection symmetries, but does it hold for **every** symmetry (scaling and translation, for example)?

Furthermore, is it there any proof for this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the transformation: $A: \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ that leaves the static charge density preserved 
$$(A\rho)(\vec{r}) = \rho(\vec{r}).$$
Next is the Poisson equation
$$ (\nabla^2 V)(\vec{r}) = - \frac{\rho(\vec{r})}{\epsilon_0} $$ with appropriate boundary conditions. If $\rho$ is a symmetry of $A$, then $ \nabla^2 V$ is a symmetry as well. This is shown by acting on the Poisson equation with $A$. To prove that $V$ is a symmetry one must first prove that boundary conditions remain the same. First boundary condition $\displaystyle{\lim_{r->\infty} V(\vec{r}) = const}$ certainly remains the same.

Second Dirichlet/Neumann boundary condition (See Jackson - Classical Electrodynamics 3rd edition) is specifying potentials/potential normals along the surfaces of conductors. But if $\rho$ on conductors is unchanged than their surfaces must also be unchanged (because charge can only gather at the surface of the conductor) - hence the boundary conditions are unchanged. Considering the uniqueness of the Poisson equation one can conclude that electrostatic potential $V$ remains the same.

I only spoke in terms of conductors and densities. What about point charges? You could approximate a point charge with a small conducting sphere of small radius $\eta$ with surface potential $\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 \eta}$ and let $\eta \rightarrow 0$ which is covered by the case above.

Comment: Clearly one can always come up with boundary conditions for the Poisson equation that would break the symmetry imposed by the source charge distribution. So the statement in the textbook is somewhat incomplete. I guess boundary conditions can be described as effect of induced charges, so assuming all charges - the source charges and induced charges - have certain symmetry it becomes a correct statement.